# getting Cannot call 'plot' with arguments when trying to draw a line under Tradingview

Tags: pine-script

I am using Tradingview Pinescript 4.0

My goal is  to create a line that changes color (based on an input value). If "short" is chosen, it will print a red line of 20 bars in length. If "long" is chosen, then the bar would be green.

I tried the code below

```
x_color     = color.yellow
x_transp    = 100.0

if enter_long 
    x_color  := color.teal
    x_transp := 0

if enter_short 
    x_color  := color.red
    x_transp := 0
```

plot(i_entry_level, color=x_color,  transp=x_transp, linewidth=2, title="Start Level")

But I get the following as an error message:

> line 146: Cannot call 'plot' with arguments (input integer,
> color=series[color], transp=series[float], linewidth=literal integer,
> title=literal string); available overloads: plot(series[float], const
> string, series[color], input integer, input integer, input bool, input
> integer, input float, series[integer], input bool, series[float],
> const bool, input integer, const integer, string) => plot;
> plot(<arg_series_type>, const string, <arg_color_type>, input integer,
> input integer, input bool, input integer, input float,
> series[integer], input bool, series[float], const bool, input integer,
> const integer, string) => plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `transp` parameter does not allow the use of series. You can use a workaround.

```
x_color     = color.new(color.yellow, 100)
//x_transp    = 100.0

if enter_long 
    x_color  := color.new(color.teal, 0)
    //x_transp := 0

if enter_short 
    x_color  := color.new(color.red, 0)
    //x_transp := 0

plot(i_entry_level, color=x_color, linewidth=2, title="Start Level")
```